# How to Create A Toggle with a Var to change state in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a simple click toggle with vanilla JS, but I seem to have hit a wall.  I've create a variable to change the state of the function after clicking, but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm starting to pull my hair out a bit now.

There is a pen here to show the problem: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/dWByjx

The code is here for quick reference:

HTML

```
<div class="box">Click Me</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
font-family: arial;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}
```

JS

```
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box')[0];
var isBlue = true;

if (isBlue === true) {

  box.onclick = function() {

  box.style.background = 'red';
  isBlue = false;
  }  

} else {

  box.onclick = function() {

  box.style.background = 'blue';
  isBlue = true;
  }

}
```

Any help ideas would be wonderful.

Emily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test `if (isBlue)` is evaluated only once, at the beginning, and installs the `onclick` listener that changes color from blue to red. From then on, that same listener will always be executed, and set the color to red.

Instead, put your if/else logic *inside* the function:

```
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box')[0];
var isBlue = true;
box.onclick = function() {
  if (isBlue) {
    box.style.background = 'red';
    isBlue = false;
  }
  else {
    box.style.background = 'blue';
    isBlue = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hugues. That was driving me mad.